# Delete row in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have written the code to delete row from the csv file The code the working fine before but it had one problem the contents of the file were printed in single line i was trying to fix that but can't seem to find the solution for problem.This the code that i have written:

import csv

```
patron_list=[]
def delete_patron():
    delete_id=input('Enter id to delete:')
    with open ('Patron.csv','r') as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            patron_list.append(row)
            for field in row:
                if field==delete_id:
                    patron_list.remove(row)

    with open ('Patron.csv','w') as csv_file:
        writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(patron_list)
```

This is the output:

```
"['[""[\'ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME\\\\n100,Sarah,Banks\\\\n101,Ben,James\\\\n102,Dave,Big\""]', '[]']",[]
```

It would be really helpful if someone could tell me what i did wrong.

Comment: Change to `.writerows(`, you want to write a list of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

patron_list is a list of lists not a list , try using writerows instead:

```
patron_list=[]
def delete_patron():
    delete_id=input('Enter id to delete:')
    with open ('Patron.csv','r') as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            patron_list.append(row)
            for field in row:
                if field==delete_id:
                    patron_list.remove(row)

    with open ('Patron.csv','w') as csv_file:
        writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerows(patron_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to figure out what i did wrong for hours.

Comment: You are welcome , glad to help. If you want you can accept my answer for the question.